# How to add a count to a Ruby String (SiriProxy)

Tags: ruby, raspberry-pi, siri

I make a SiriProxy using The Three Little Piggies, I played around with it, now I can control my room and my garage door with Siri. I decided to let my pi send a tweet to me every time the garage door opens or close, I am using this command in the Plugin file

```
system("sudo twidge update \"@idoodler The garage door was just opened the XXX time\"")`
```

instead of the XXX I like to have the number of openings. I need this because twitter don't allow duplicates. I don't need the opening number, I just need a method to make every tweet unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you just add a timestamp or something to differentiate:

```
tweet = Time.now.strftime("@idoodler The door was opened at %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

Comment: Thank you, this is great a great idea! I am new to Ruby, can you tell me how I can add the string to the command?

Comment: Just do `system("sudo twidge update \"#{tweet}\"")` after the line posted by @tadman

Comment: OK, It works, but I get a wired number instead of the correct timestamp 2013-14-04/19/13 Apr:04:1366402495. Do you know how to solve this?

Comment: Oh, sorry, messed up the [formatting](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Time.html#method-i-strftime). Answer adjusted.

Comment: You can also do: `system("sudo","twidge","update",tweet)` to avoid having to properly enquote your tweet. Be super extra careful when running shell commands that include `sudo`.